# How to check Network/Shared Folder stability?

Tags: c#, network-programming, shared-directory

At work we have a shared folder where I do some data collection. From my computer I have to make sure, that the server is not down during data collection.

So, my approach would be, in an interval of few minutes I will connect and reconnect to my server a several times (if it fails, then stop data collection and wait or do next task)

What is the best way to connect and reconnect to a network drive/shared folder?
I would do something like

```
public bool checkNet(UNCPath)
{
int connected = 0;
bool unstable = true;
while(unstable)
{
SubfunctionConnect(UNCPath); //connect to network using cmd 'net use' command
if(directory.exists(UNCPath) 
{
++connected;
}
else
{
connected = 0;
}
}
if(connected >= 3) unstable = false; //after 3 in arrow  successful connections then leave loop and proceed further tasks
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm maintaining a project which has a similar feature to your requirement.

In that feature, we use [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2) to monitor all kinds of operation of specific UNC location.
You can implement the `OnError` event which will be triggered while the UNC path is not available.

You can check the link above for detail, still, a short sample here

```
using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"\\your unc path"))
{
    // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
    // the renaming of files or directories.
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                         | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                         | NotifyFilters.FileName
                         | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

    // Only watch text files.
    watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

    watcher.Created += (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine($"Created {e.Name}"); };
    watcher.Deleted += (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine($"Deleted {e.Name}"); };
    watcher.Error += (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine($"Error {e.GetException()}"); };


    // Begin watching.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    // Wait for the user to quit the program.
    Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit the sample.");
    while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
}
```